# PHPUnit setUp method

Tags: phpunit

I have a problem. Simple code

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class StringTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $stack = '';

    public function testModify()
    {
        $this->stack .= 'modify';
        $this->assertEquals('modify', $this->stack);
    }

    public function testEmpty()
    {
        $this->assertEquals('', $this->stack);
    }

}
```

Why validation pass? Why in second test `$this->stack` doesn't has `modify`value?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I started learning phpunit and this result surprised me ;)

Comment: Sure, you can write test that depends each other by the result of the first

Answer (score 2):

Each test (each test method) is run in isolation (on a separate test object).

Comment: I read about it. Is turning off process isolation great idea? I watched a few tutorials and programmers was setting it to false.

Comment: This is not process isolation, that would give you even more isolation.